# Standart rowwise vector matrix operations

Tags: blas, intel-mkl

I am searching for rowwise vector matrix operations( I think that should be  BLAS level 2 routines). For example to substruct a vector from a matrix rowwise, or to normalize matrix by it rows sum. Are there such optimized standard routines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such operation in BLAS. All the available subroutines are listed here: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node145.html

You can write your own subroutines and call BLAS level 1 for jobs like norm, axpy, etc... However, the gain in performance is generally modest.

-> BLAS is really important for matrix-matrix (or matrix-vector) products where cache management, data locality and access pattern make a really big difference (in perfs).

Comment: There are routines like cblas_?scal and gain in performance for the vector matrix operations should be greater.  We got bad register usage if vector size is not multiple of registers count. Mb this is so because vector - matrix ops are not so popular.